# Multiple choice poll

Tags: 7, polls

I thought this would be out of the box, but it doesn't seem so.

I'm looking for a way to be able to have a multiple choice poll where users can select more than one answer.

Is this even possible with the Drupal 7 Core Poll Module?

If Core Poll does not allow this, are there some other modules out there which are not in dev?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform). It functions differently from Poll, but it's also much more robust and has plenty of additional modules that extend it.

And, of course, creating a question that allows multiple choices is a snap.

Comment: That's a great idea! I'll check that out.

Comment: Okay, there are two problems with this solution: 1. a guest should not be able to vote again. 2. the setup is really an overkill. For me it is okay, but I think it might be a pain for others.

Comment: 1. You can set a per-user submission limit, which will go by IP address for anonymous users. 2. Yes, it probably is overkill, especially if all you're doing is a simple poll with one question and you only need the multiple choice functionality.